# ASP.NET webforms (username & password) to authenticate SSO [itfoxtec-identity-saml2]

Tags: asp.net, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have ASP.NET webforms applications with a log in page. I tried to use single sign-on feature for these applications using "itfoxtec-identity-saml2". I have tried some articles posted but could not get proper solution for webforms.

Once credentials (username & password) are entered and I click the login button to authenticate, Idp (service) successfully authenticates and redirects to main page.

What are the elements to transfer to IDP? How to implement in webforms?
Can someone help me with any sample code or article for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that I do not have sample code or a library that support ASP.NET webforms.

A solution could be to upgrade your ASP.NET webforms application to ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web Pages.